# Getting permission denied error when downloading a html page as html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, wicked-pdf

This is my shortlisted action and shortlisted.html.erb , when clicked on download the list of shortlisted candidates should get downloaded.

```
def shortlisted
 ids= AppliedJob.shortlisted.pluck(:user_id)
 @shortlisted=User.where(id:ids)
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.pdf do
    render pdf: "file_name",
               template: 'users/shortlisted',
               layout: 'pdf.html.erb',
               page_size: 'A4',
               disposition: 'attachment',
               formats: [:html]
   end
 end
end
```

shortlisted.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "download", shortlisted_path(format: :pdf)  %>
```

[image: This is what I am getting when trying to download]

Comment: Could you check the permissions / owners of the mentioned directory ? It seems that the user, which runs the ruby-process, may not access the directory.

Comment: You do not need pluck. Ever. `@shortlisted = User.where(id: AppliedJob.shortlisted.select(:user_id))`

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**